Blue spots and pink spots during rusting experiment with potassium hecacyanoferrate (III) solution and phenolphthalein
I'm referring to the rusting experiment where an iron nail is coiled with a metal that either has a less positive/more negative E⁰ value or more positive/less negative E⁰ value then iron, and is then places with a text tube with hot agar solution containing potassium hecacyanoferrate (III) solution and phenolphthalein solution.
From what I understand, the formation of pink spots implies the presence of OH- ions, and blue spots imply the presence is $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ ions
In the case where the metal coiled around the iron had a more positive/less negative E⁰ value, iron will undergo oxidation and rust to form $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ ions, and will then react with the OH- ions in the solution to form Fe(OH)₂. In this case, there will be low intensity of pink spots and high intensity of blue spots. I get the pinks spots are less because there is a low concentration of OH- ions after reacting with the $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ ions, but then shouldn't there also be a low concentration of $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ ions? since its the one that reacted with the OH- ions in the first place?
Then in the case where metal has a more negative/less positive E⁰ value ,there is a high intensity of pink spots and low/no intensity of blue spots. The blue spots I get, since the metal is chosen to be oxidized, not Fe, there are no $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ ions. But then can't the metal ions react with the OH- ions, like $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ did, causing low intensity of pink spots again?
Edit: added a pic for clarification on the experiment
Mg ribbon will cause high intensity of pink spots whereas copper strip will cause high intensity of blue spots


It will be helpful if you include an image of the experiment for those who may not be familiar with it. By the way, I will not talk about "electropositive metals" it could be quite confusing. In my opinion is better to think about the reduction electrode potentials.

Blue spots:   Either hexacyanoferrate (II) + Fe3+, either hexacyanoferrate (III) + Fe2+.  Mixed valences are required.

You may find this YouTube video instructive:  Nailing corrosion - teaching rusting from an electrochemical perspective  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZgfeiuB4SvE"

@PAEP oh ok I edited it dy

@PAEP and I saw the video. It kind of helped but didn't rlly answer my question. I'm just curious about the sort of inconsistency when it comes to the formation? if that makes snese sry

@Poutnik and ya sorry got it mixed up. Thx ya

Yes this would make a good gender reveal prop. But do not do it live at the party. Do it in the lab, with proper equipment and procedures for cyanide-containing reactants, and take a video to the party.

When the iron is oxidized to iron(II), as with the copper wrapping, it precipitates a mixed-valence iron-cyanide complex called Prussian blue. To wit,
$\ce{4 Fe^{2+} + 4 Fe(CN)6^{3-} -> \underset{Prussian blue}{Fe^{III}_4[Fe^{II}(CN)6]_3}(s) + Fe(CN)6^{4-}}$
Thus the blue spots are this Prussian blue precipitate, not any dissolved iron(II). You need the ferricyanide complex for the Prussian blue to form and the blue spots to work.
With an electropositive metal wrapping such as magnesium, hydroxide formation does occur; but in general electropositive metals have hydroxides with enough solubility to make the solution basic before they precipitate, and that makes the pink spots in the agar/phenolphthalein. Magnesium, the metal you use in this experiment, will form a binary hydroxide-water solution with a pH of about 10.

oh so in the electropositive metal case,the pink spots r formed bcs the solution is in general an alkali,right? Then how bout the hydroxide ions formed in the cooler wrapping case doesn't that also make the solution alkaline? But thx,helped to clear up that Mg part there

With Cu you'd still precipitate tge hydroxide as Fe(OH)2.

ohhh and Fe(OH)2 is not basic correct? or not very basic compared to Mg(OH)2?
